# Is there a mass spectrometer software that can measure the mass of a proton

Tags: mass, simulations, software, protons, mass-spectrometry

I spent a lot of hours looking for mass spectrometer software (or Cathode-ray simulator) that can measure the mass of a proton or any sub atomic particle. Until now I only found software that work on isotopes, organic mixtures and other compounds.

For my school project, I need a computer simulation to measure the mass of a proton (I chose the idea not my school) so any other way of measuring a proton will not be useful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a practical matter, running hydrogen through most chemical mass spectrometers *can* measure of the proton mass, though you need to insure that the ionization step is energetic enough to get a significant number of molecules dissociated (you need to measure $\mathrm{H}^+$ and not $(\mathrm{H}_2)^+$).

Comment: That said, as a philosophical point, I don't care for language like "a simulation that can *measure* [some input parameter]". In this case these programs are going to have a value of the proton mass built-in and the best they can do is give you that value back. A more accurate description of what you want is *"a program than can simulate and experiment that would be able to determine the proton mass"*. However, there are simulations whose results are deeper than replicating their input parameters as in the case of lattice QCD codes.

Comment: @dmckee I will try the idea with the hydrogen atom. thanks

Comment: @dmckee Hello again. What programs do you use to simulate a mass spectrometer? The two programs that I tried to work with did not have a hydrogen atom (or most likely I do not know how to use them properly). Thanks

Comment: I *don't* simulate mass spectrometers in the way that you mean. I've simulate particle physics detectors that incorporate the same principles in the past, using custom code built on the Geant3 framework, but .. that doesn't really address your need.