# Is there a mass spectrometer software that can measure the mass of a hydrogen atom

Tags: mass, simulations, hydrogen, software, mass-spectrometry

For a school project I need to measure the mass of a hydrogen atom either as a lab experiment or with a computer simulation. Since I don't have the appropriate equipment for the experiment, does anyone know a mass spectrometer software that can find the mass of a hydrogen atom?

Thanks.

Comment: Related by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450827/25301

Comment: Hi, welcome to [physics.se]! I've closed this as a duplicate of your other question. The core of both questions is whether there is software to measure particle masses (about which there is a useful philosophical observation on your other question already). Whether the particle of interest is a proton, a hydrogen atom, or something else seems like a distraction from your main point. I suggest you edit your other question to make it more general.

Comment: You can search either [physlets](https://www.compadre.org/physlets/) or [open source physics](https://www.compadre.org/osp/) for lab simulations, but you still seem confused about both the role of software in these kinds of issues and about what exactly you can expect to exist. Outside of dedicated teaching tools there is simple no reason for people to write software with this kind of goal because it won't be doing what you hope it will be doing: software for simulating an experimental proton mass measurement **will have the proton mass written in and can only regurgitate that value**.